# Event type for event listener callback function - React & Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to handle scroll event so a new class name can be added to an element upon scrolling.

What I have done:

- Created a callback function for event listener
- use useEffect and addEventListener

Here's the code:

```
  const onScrollHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent):void => {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('onScrollBar')) {
      e.target.classList.add('onScrollBar');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler, true);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler, true);
    };
  }, []);
```

The issue I got:

- From addEventListener, the `onScrollHandler` shows this error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "scroll", listener: (this: Window, ev: Event) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: React.ChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Window, ev: Event) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'e' and 'ev' are incompatible.
        Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'ChangeEvent<Element>': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(e: React.ChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type '(e: React.ChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
        Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
          Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<Element>'.ts(2769)
```

I think this is something to do with the `e: React.ChangeEvent`. So what should be the correct event type in this case?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think it's `document.addEventListener`

Comment: @Vector-Hector I've tried replacing window with document but it doesn't work. the `onScrollHandler` still throws error.

I have tried to change the event type from `React.ChangeEvent` to `Event`, the `onScrollHandler` doesn't throw error. But now I can't use `e.target.classList...` anymore :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to use `document` to add the listener, or that scoll listener will not do anything.

It seems `React.ChangeEvent` is only applicable for `<select>`, `<input>` or `<textarea>` onChange events.
So you need to use the type `Event` for scroll events and such. Now, the scroll target is most of the time the DOM, which does not have a `classList`. To get the proper type, I used the `as` keyword and checked if it has a `classList`.

Here's my full code:

```js
const onScrollHandler = (e: Event) => {
    if (!e.target)
        return

    const target = e.target as Element
    if (target.classList === undefined) // ensure it's not the DOM
        return

    if (!target.classList.contains('onScrollBar')) 
        target.classList.add('onScrollBar');
};
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler, true);
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler, true);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. This is the same approach to one of my colleague's solution. I tried it and works wonder for me :D

Answer (score 1):

My colleague has helped me with this solution and it works wonders for me :D

So basically, the event type should be changed as `Event` and when calling `e.target`, we need to specify it as `Element`

Here's the fix:

```
  const onScrollHandler = (e: Event):void => {
    if((e.target as Element).classList.contains('onScrollBar')) {
      ((e.target as Element).classList.add('onScrollBar'))
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler, true);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler, true);
    };
  }, []);
```